# JSX String Literal

Tags: jsx

Are there any performance issues related to using JSX syntax for string literals like so

```
<div class={"container"}/>
```

as opposed to

```
<div class="container"/>
```

I understand that the two work exactly the same and that the first option is unnecessary, but I am just curious if doing this at a large scale (a lot) contributes to the performance of an application.

Comment: When jsx transpiles down to js, it should be same, I think. Not sure completely.

Comment: @Pavitra is right. Shouldn't make a difference after transpiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference - it both compiles down to the same thing. You can try it out here: https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=%3E%202%25%2C%20ie%2011%2C%20safari%20%3E%209&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAPAEwJYDcbADZwQSIBEoYUcGYApgE4kwD0AfANwBQ50MARkqkw58hYgG8y4StXokAvs3ZA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2

```
const a = <div class="container" />;
const b = <div class={"container"} />;
```

becomes

```
"use strict";

var a = React.createElement("div", { "class": "container" });
var b = React.createElement("div", { "class": "container" });
```

Hence, no difference in performance. The curly brackets around the `"container"` string just switch back from the jsx syntax to standard javascript syntax. String literals are interpreted the same in both ways, which means there is no difference.